# Power dissipation of TLC6C5712-Q1 LED Driver IC

Tags: led-driver, shift-register, power-dissipation, dissipation

I am using this TI [LED Driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc6c5712-q1.pdf) IC to drive 9 LEDs

I want to calculate the Power Dissipation of the Resistor (20k 1% 0402) which I have connected to the IREF pin.

To calculate the power dissipation of that resistor, I am using ((V^2)/R) formula, where I am taking V in the range given in that datasheet as (1.204V to 1.254V) - Referring 6.5 section, page 5. Am I correct? And is the current through the 20k resistor sourced from the Vcc supply or from where?

Also I am trying to calculate the overall power dissipation and the Junction temperature of the IC.

Since TLC6C5712-Q1 does not have internal MOSFETs, how to calculate the power dissipation of the IC.

Can someone help me how this LED Driver IC internal architecture is different from [LED Driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc6c598.pdf) IC which has internal MOSFETs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in taking the reference voltage to calculate power dissipated. \$V^2/R\$

Take the worst case voltage (1.254 V).

---

Edit 2: **How do i calculate power consumed by the driver**:

Supply current times the input voltage will give the power consumption of the device.

[image]

---

Edit 3: Here are my observation:

1. The TLC6C598 is a simple current sink. It can sink upto 50 mA (limited by rating of the transitors). The TLC6C5712 is a **constant current driver**
2. The current limit in TLC6C598 set using external resistors (one per channel). The current limit in TLC6C5712 is set using single resistor (at IREF pin).
3. TLC6C598 is for simple LED designs where as the TLC6C5712  is used for compensating LED  color temperature and brightness.
4. PWM support is there in both

[image]
[image]

---

Edit 3:

The blue colored section, will be very tiny. you can ignore.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Could you also edit your answer to provide me clarity on the other questions.

Comment: Can you please provide more details for my question

Comment: Give me some time

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a small query, when you say " Supply current times the input voltage" , when you say the input voltage, due to mean the input voltage of the IC, or the voltage which is present at the OUT pins in the IC?

Comment: Input voltage applied to the IC. 5V in the snapshot shown above

Comment: I am finding some difficulty in this understanding of Power Dissipation. If you search for the power dissipation in the TLC6C5712 datasheet, you find that the middle term is mentioned for each channel voltage at OUT pin and its current. So, ideally, It must be the voltage at the OUT pin and the LED current, right? It cannot be the supply voltage, right?

Comment: Could you please clarify my query

Comment: Please see edit 3

Comment: Thank you for the edit. My query is, Assume I connect an LED whose Anode is at 5V, with no series resistor and the forward voltage of the LED is 2V with a forward current of 20mA. The power dissipation for the IC at the OUT pin, would be (5V-2V)*20mA, right? We need to subtract the forward voltage of the LED from the voltage present at the anode of the LED to get the voltage which is present at the OUT pin so as the get the power dissipated at the OUT pin of the IC? Am I correct? Is my calculation right?

Comment: The above calculation, I have done for only ONE OUT channel of the IC pin. Whether it is correct?

Comment: You are right. 3 V will be \$V_{out}/$. And the same equation as in edit 3 will be used to calculate total power dissipation.